# Inserting Triple Quotes Into a JSON Script

Tags: javascript, java, json, string, minecraft

I am trying to program a script for the game "Minecraft", and the game involves a lot of JSON scripting. I am trying to add a command block which will place a sign on a wall that can be clicked resulting in a title being displayed. My command is like this.

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ wall_sign 0 replace {Text1:"{\"text\":\"My Sign\",\"color\":\"red\",
\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/title @p title 
{} < Problem Area
\"}}"}
```

What am  I supposed to do at the problem area? Placing two backslashes like this

```
\\"
```

doesn't work, so I'm kind of confused. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This validates correctly for me:

```
{
    "Text1": "{\"text\":\"My Sign\",\"color\":\"red\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":{\"/title @p title  {} < Problem Area\"}}}"
}
```

Depending on how you want to escape you need to make sure that the unescaped string matches the desired level.

```
\\\" 'unescapes' to \"
\\\\\\\" 'unescapes' to \\\" -> \" -> "
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I was wondering how to place quotes inside of quotes inside of quotes, like this.

Comment: " FIRST QUOTE \" SECOND QUOTE [?] < Third Quote... > [?] \" "

Comment: When I write it like this i get it validated as proper json. (changed answer)

Comment: Hope that works out for you :) But I really recomment to just use objects and json-parse them. It works the same on both ends and there is very low risc of stuff getting messed up.

Comment: Lovely. Give it a thumbs up so I can set bounties ;) Or check the answer as solving the problem.